# Pass variable to laravel model boot

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.8 for my application. I have variables call "lot" and when I delete one, I want to perform other actions.

So I use deleting function on my model, everything works OK.

But know I have a function on my controller to delete many "lots" and I want actions to be perform only when all "lots" have been delete and not on every "lots" delete.

So I wonder if there is a way to achieve this ? Maybe we can pass a variable to boot functions to trigger or not the function ?

My model looks like this :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function($modele) {

        Etage::doesntHave('lots')->delete();

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model events are been designed to work for single models.

You should use Laravel [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events) instead, not tied to Models.

In `EventServiceProvider.php` register a new Event/Listener in the `$listens` array, like

```
LotsDeleted::class => PerformOtherAction::class
```

Create those classes with `php artisan event:generate`

Then, when you have finished deleting all your `Lot` objects, trigger the event with

```
event(new LotsDeleted());
```

The `handle()` function of your listener will be called and you can perform other actions.

Comment: Thank for the explication. What's the difference between event and helper function so ?

Comment: I don't know if I got your question right: the helper function is just a convenient way to call the event dispatcher, that will fire the event object.